# why no initial conditions are required in the differential equation/eigenfunctions problem of orthogonal polynomials?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, orthogonal-polynomials, sturm-liouville, chebyshev-polynomials

in section 4.2 of the book "Special functions, a graduate text"  says the following:

We return to the three cases corresponding to the classical polynomials, with interval $I$, weight $w$, and eigenvalue equation of the form
$$p(x)\psi_n (x) + q(x)\psi_n(x) + \lambda_n\psi_n(x) = 0,\qquad q = \frac{(pw)}{w}$$
The cases are
$$I = \mathbb{R},\ w(x) = e^{-x^2},\ p(x) = 1,\ q(x) = -2x;$$
$$I = \mathbb{R}_+,\ w(x) = x^\alpha e^{-x},\ \alpha> -1,\ p(x) = x,\ q(x) = α + 1 - x$$

Also, the chebyshev polynomials are solution for the next "Sturm-Liouville" problem
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}\phi''-x\phi'+n^2\phi=0,$$

Why in the above cases are no boundary conditions imposed on the differential equations?

Answer (score 2):

Eigenproblems are always homogeneous, so you get homogeneous boundary conditions for the values or limit of them at the interval ends. As always, solutions have to be non-trivial, non-zero.